# Create uneven columns with dynamic width

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to create 3 divs that perform as columns.

The left should stick to the left and be 175px.
The right should stick to the right and be 175px.
The middle should be 100% of the remaining width. (100%-(175px-175px))

This code is not working and I cannot figure out why.  I feel like it is all correct but I cannot figure it out.

I tried javascript resize, what do you think?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   var newwidth = $(window).width() - 350;
   $("main_middle").css({width: newwidth+'px'});
});

$(window).resize(function() {
   var newwidth = $(window).width() - 350;
   $("main_middle").css({width: newwidth+'px'});
});
</script>

<div style="width:100%;height:100%;position:relative;margin:auto;">

<div style="position:fixed;width:175px;height:100%;margin-left:0;background-color:#222;">
</div>

<div id="main_middle" name="main_middle" style="float:left;position:absolute;height:100%;margin-left:175px;margin-top:38px;background-color:white;border-left:1px solid #A9A9A9;top:0px;left:0px;margin-right:200px;">
</div>


<div style="float:right;right:0px;position:relative;border-left:1px solid #A9A9A9;height:100%;background-color:white;margin-top:38px;width:200px;">
</div>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What "is not working"?  You don't need JavaScript to do this, css is more than enough.   
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if its a typo but you are missing the # in your JQuery call

```
$("main_middle")
```

should be

```
$("#main_middle")
```

Comment: Incredible find haha!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check this code and compare it with what you have

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="left">
    Port side text...
</div>
<div id="right">
    Starboard side text...
</div>
<div id="middle">
    Middle column text...
</div>
<div id="footer">
    Footer text...
</div>
</body>
```

And here's the CSS code:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div#header {
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: aqua;
    padding: 1px;
}
div#left {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}
div#right {
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: green;
}
div#middle {
    padding: 0px 160px 5px 160px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: silver;
}
div#footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I don't think you need to use javascript for this.